# Postgresql: remove ability to query every row in a table

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, supabase, supabase-database

I have the following table called "profile":

`id, name, created_at`

Every user ( with SupaBase ) has his own row in the "profile" table with his user_id as the key ( id )
I added RLS so that only the user can update/delete his own row but everyone else can only select the row ( anyone can see his profile )

This works great but the issue is that someone could query every single user in the table using `SELECT * FROM profile` or something similar. I only want people to be able to view a row if they already have their "id" or their "name" with a `WHERE` statement.

The only solution I see is to remove the ability to SELECT the table ( basically make it private ) and make an API that will query with the admin key ( bypasses the RLS ). That way, no one could query the whole table and the client would just call the API which would then query the data.

However, I would like to query directly from the client so I want to know if there is a different solution that doesn't require an API in between. Currently learning Postgresql so I'm probably missing something really simple.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot obtain the underlining query within your row level security policy, so the exact solution that you are looking for cannot be done, but there is a workaround.

You can deny all access for selecting user, and then create the following database function. `security definer` at the end means that this function will bypass row level security.

```sql
create or replace function get_user(user_id uuid)
returns public.users
language sql
as
$$
  select * from public.users where id = get_user.user_id;
$$ security definer;
```

With the above function in place, you can query the data like this from your client:

```js
const { data, error} = await supabase.rpc('get_user', { user_id: 'target_user_id_to_query' })
```

With this, anyone can only query the user if they know their user_id, and you can still query the user directly from the client.

Comment: This is the solution I was about to post after reading your question. It should be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 2):

See [Row Security Policies](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-rowsecurity.html) page, which has your exact scenario as an example:

> When row security is enabled on a table (with `ALTER TABLE ... ENABLE ROW LEVEL SECURITY`), all normal access to the table for selecting rows or modifying rows must be allowed by a row security policy.
>
> [...]
>
> If no role is specified, or the special user name `PUBLIC` is used, then the policy applies to all users on the system. To allow all users to access only their own row in a users table, a simple policy can be used:
>
> ```
> CREATE POLICY user_policy ON users
>     USING (user_name = current_user);
> ```

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't see how this would help. I want everyone to be able to SELECT the row but I don't want people to be able the query the whole table using SELECT * FROM profile. Basically I only want people to be able to get a profile if they have their id.

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood, I thought you only wanted users to get the row of their own ID.

Answer (score 1):

I had the exact same problem in several tables, and I wanted to use the supabase database client, to mantain the ability to query, sort, paginate, etc.

Looking at the supabase documentation, I saw that you could access the request headers at the RLS, with a function (https://supabase.com/docs/learn/auth-deep-dive/auth-policies, user_agent example to access the browser user-agent)

So, I create a function to get a custom header element, in my case named "query_data":

```
create or replace function get_header_query_data()
    returns text
    language sql
    as $$
      select nullif(current_setting('request.headers', true)::json->>'query_data', '')::text;
    $$;
```

In the tables with user_id, I add the following RLS for select:

```
(get_header_query_data() = user_id)
```

So, with this elements, I can query with the supabase client, only adding in the header the parameter 'query-data' with the id of the user I want to select, and I can still use aditional queries, paginate the results, sort, etc.

The only thing I miss if that I need to create a new supabase client each time, to pass the proper headings, like so:

```
const supabase = createClient(supabaseUrl, supabaseAnonKey, {
  global: { 
    headers: {
      query_data: 'user-name-example',
    },
  }
});
```

I don't know how to change the headers dynamically.