# Supabase realtime - RLS to only allow delete if url /xyz matches xyz in DB column

Tags: postgresql, supabase, row-level-security

I have a table "boards" with a column "edit_link" which is a randomized string

I want users who visit the page /edit/xyz to be able to only update and delete the row where edit_link is xyz. In realtime.

I looked at this using RPC: [Postgresql: remove ability to query every row in a table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74283527/postgresql-remove-ability-to-query-every-row-in-a-table)
But not sure if that can translate to realtime.

I haven't found a way to send a parameter with my call for the RLS policy to use

How would i restrict it in Supabase? there is no login. just a unique url.

Comment: You don't need a row-level security for this at all. "User who visits the page" is meaningless, what you really mean is that users can update or delete **all rows whose `edit_link` token they know**. They'll pass this token in their request, you simply translate that into a `WHERE edit_link_token = $1` condition.

Comment: The WHERE clause, do you mean on client side, if so what would prevent any bad intended user, to inspect the network tab and mimic and alter the call to delete all rows in table instead?

Comment: The `WHERE` clause should not be generated on the client, no. It must be generated by your backend (or the supabase backend configured by you). The client must not be able to directly issue `DELETE` queries on the database, just like they should not be able to issue `SELECT *` queries on that table.

Comment: If its not an RLS, how would i force supabase to append this WHERE clause on every request to "board" table and how would i pass $1 param along with the request?

Comment: Well how do you want to pass the link with every request to the table at all?

Comment: "*If its not an RLS, how would i force supabase to append this WHERE clause*" - just like shown in [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74284507/1048572) to the question that you linked

Comment: Bergi draws an important distinction - if you (your backend outside end users' control) handle the queries, RLS only saves you some permission control in each one, but you can still implement all of it as `WHERE` conditions. If the users do (potentially have a way to) control their queries while operating all under the same db user, then by design they also have a way to interfere with each other. RLS is more suitable for when you have different users accessing common relations.

Comment: Right, I can create my own proxy API to handle it, but with Supabase serverless api its even recommended that the API key is public and sent along with every request, which is why they rely on RLS (and auth, not using it here.) to secure it.

In the linked post, they lock everything down in RLS, and call a function in Supabase that bypasses RLS. But i don't think i can use it with realtime DB.

Zagereks solution seems feasable, i just wanted to explore this option first, to see if i missed something. Maybe i still do?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [custom setting](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/runtime-config-custom.html) to hold the current link, then refer to it from the RLS: [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/Qp3A-ln3)

```sql
create policy only_xyz on boards 
using      (edit_link = current_setting('public.pass_the_current_link_here',true)) 
with check (edit_link = current_setting('public.pass_the_current_link_here',true));
```

As long as the setting is always set to the currently visited page, it'll only allow operations on the rows belonging to it:

```
set foo.pass_the_current_link_here='example.com/mypage';

insert into boards (edit_link) values ('example.com/mypage') returning *;
```

| id | edit_link |
| --- | --- |
| 2 | example.com/mypage |

Setting mismatch will throw an error on `insert`:

```
insert into boards (edit_link) values ('example.com/another_page') returning *;
```

> ```
> ERROR:  new row violates row-level security policy for table "boards"
> ```

All `select`, `update`, `merge` and `delete` statements will find nothing unless the setting matches. In case of `update` and `merge` both new and old values need to match (rules in the policy `using` part forces the new one to match, `with check` guards the old one):

```
delete from boards where edit_link='example.com/another_page' returning *;
```

> ```
> DELETE 0
> ```

```
update boards set edit_link='example.com/mypage' 
  where edit_link='example.com/another_page' 
  returning *;
```

> ```
> UPDATE 0
> ```

Comment: The setting I suggested could potentially be altered by a user if they are free to issue their own statements. You could keep session data isolated and give everyone a secret token you'd verify in a subquery in your RLS policy, but those can be leaked, cracked, exchanged, plus I expect this sort of approach is what you had reserves about when specifying "real time".

Comment: RLS-verified token kind of emulates user separation and RLS puts the token verification objects beyond the scope of the end user role, unlike `where` injection.